# Ionic 3: playing an Icecast/Shoutcast audio stream

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, audio-streaming, icecast

I'm working on an internet radio app using the Ionic 3 framework. I came up with this simple code that uses the HTML5 audio element. Many people suggest that this approach is better than using the **@ionic-native/streaming-media** plugin.

The following is my implementation:

**HTML**

```
<audio id="audioStream" src="http://icecastserverIP:8000/icecastchannel" autoplay></audio>

<a href="#" id="player">
  <div class="btn-play" id="con-btn-play">
    <img src="assets/img/btn-play.png" alt="Play">
  </div>
</a>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var audio = $('#audioStream')[0]


    // Preloader animation

    audio.addEventListener('waiting', function () {
        $('#con-btn-play').html('<img src="assets/img/preloader.gif">');
    }, false);
    audio.addEventListener('playing', function () {
        $('#con-btn-play').html('<img src="assets/img/btn-pause.png">');
    }, false);


    // Play button behaviour

    $('#player').click(function(){
        if (audio.paused){
            audio.play();
            $('#con-btn-play').html('<img src="assets/img/btn-pause.png" alt="Pause">');
        }else {
            audio.pause();
            $('#con-btn-play').html('<img src="assets/imgs/btn-play.png" alt="Play">');
        }
    });

});
```

The stream plays fine in Android and iOS. However, **at the slightest connection drop the audio will stop and won't reconnect**. Not to mention that if I press pause, the stream will continue using data in the background.

My question is: is there a better way to handle Icecast streams? A third-party plugin that you would recommend for a better buffering management and playing experience?

Comment: If you're interested, I have code based on MediaSource Extensions that you can license for a commercial project.  Feel free to contact me at brad@audiopump.co.  Otherwise, see my answer below for getting started on implementing something similar yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, at the slightest connection drop the audio will stop and won't reconnect.

You can reconnect with your own code by handling the `error` event on the Audio element.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/onerror

> Not to mention that if I press pause, the stream will continue using data in the background.

Yes, you'll want to make your own UI to control this element.  When someone pauses, you'll want to call `.stop()` instead.  By default, the audio element is assuming a regular audio file that ends at some point.

> A third-party plugin...

No plugin needed.

> ...a better buffering management and playing experience?

With the two suggestions I've made in this answer, you can have a useful experience for your users.  However, there are two other issues you haven't touched on yet which you may run into.

The first is that regular ICY metadata isn't requested, nor decoded by the browser.

The second issue is that since the browser is treating your stream like a regular audio file, it's also buffering all of that audio data into memory.  This isn't very useful for a live stream where you will never go back and play previously played audio.  (This is rarely an issue you run into, since audio data requires relatively small amount of memory, but the problem does exist.)

Both of these are solved by using [MediaSource Extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API).  With MSE, you have direct control over retrieving the data, demuxing the metadata, and pushing data to a buffer to be played back.  Since your code is in control, you can stream indefinitely without the memory leak.

Comment: Thanks Brad! If you mean the Icecast/Shoutcast metadata, I'm using the plugin done by the guys from WaveStreaming (jquery.shoutcast.js). The only issue is that is not synced properly on the song change, but as you stated, that doesn't really matter at this point.

Comment: What is this `.stop()` you speak of? I have only dreamed of such simplicity

Comment: @miknik Ah, sorry!  I just realized that's in some of my own code.  I don't have it handy at the moment, but I believe I'm destroying the audio element.  I'll check again for it later.

Comment: That's right, I checked that the `.stop()` property doesn't exist on the HTML audio tag. I'd really appreciate if you could share with us a public repo or some code snippet with us. Many thanks in advance Brad!

Comment: If the Icecast server in question runs version 2.4.2 or above you can also query the JSON api at /status-json.xsl?mount=/mountpointname for current metadata. Note that this represents metadata at that precise point in time on the server. Client side buffering might mean that your playback is at a point in time that's offset by as much as 60 seconds.

Comment: @TBR I think it's preferable to pull the metadata out of the stream itself, so that it works for streams beyond Icecast as well.

Comment: Unless you implement Ogg Metadata and ICY Metadata you won't have any. Browsers don't support either out of the box, except Firefox as vendor extensions.

Comment: @TBR Of course, and what I'm saying is I've made this implementation in JavaScript to make this work well for a browser.

Comment: I guess you're talking about your commercial implementation? That's fine for those who prefer that. A lot of the web players are for a specific service where the stream is a known factor, so it's not wrong to know about the json option. That is exactly why I implemented it.

Answer (score 2):

First thing I would recommend is in your Icecast server settings increase the values of `<queue-size>` and `<burst-size>`.

By default the server will only send clients 64kb of the audio stream as a buffer when they connect, which for a 320kbps mp3 stream is less than 2 seconds.

Setting the preload tag of your `<audio>` element to none or metadata should prevent endless data streaming on paused, alternatively you can set the `playbackRate` parameter to 0.0 or change the `src` to a null value and then call `.load()` on the audio element to disconnect clients from the stream on pause.

It's possible to have your Icecast server encode the metadata directly into the audio stream by adding an extra request header when you connect. The advantage being it's then simple to sync the metadata updates with the audio.

I wrote a basic service worker script to handle the process, It adds the necessary header to the request and then parses the returned stream to extract the metadata and create a readable stream containing just the audio data which is passed to your audio element.

The code is on Github [here](https://github.com/cryptiksouls/icecast-shoutcast-metadata-grabber) if you want to try it out.